# How to count occurrences in date range for each day on a column

Tags: mysql, function, date, stored-procedures, range

I have a problem for which a 15 minute search on SO couldn't get an answer. I have a database with a table called bugs, which is used to store some info about bugs in a system we are developing. Columns of importance are open_date, close_date and status of severity of the bug introduced. I need to make an SQL statement to display counted number of opened bugs for each of dates from a range of dates which is entered. A bug is considered open on “2012-01-01” if it is created on or
before “2012-01-01” (i.e. the same day) and closed on or after “2012-01-02” (i.e. day after that date).

I have made an sql for finding unit functionality of the requirement:

```
SELECT COUNT(DATE(Open_Date)) BugsOpen
     , DATE(Open_Date) Dated 
  FROM bugs
 WHERE DATE(open_date) <= (STR_TO_DATE('21/10/17','%d/%m/%Y')) 
   AND DATE(close_date) >= (DATE_ADD(STR_TO_DATE('21/10/17','%d/%m/%Y'),INTERVAL 1 DAY)) 
    OR close_date IS NULL);
```

Which is working but I need this in like a function call or stored procedure call, ex. showBugs('21/10/17 - 29/10/17'), to display for each of the dates in the range input in this function/procedure.

I have found a way to extract to and from dates.

> SELECT SUBSTRING('21/10/17 - 29/10/17', -19, 8) as from_date, 
>   SUBSTRING('21/10/17 - 29/10/17' FROM 12) as to_date;

But I am really having trouble writing a simple procedure. I have started writing some code:

> DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS showBugs; 
>   CREATE DEFINER = 'root'@'localhost' PROCEDURE showBugs(rangeOfDates TEXT)
>
> BEGIN
>
> SET @from_date = SUBSTRING(rangeOfDates, -19, 8);
>   SET @to_date = SUBSTRING(rangeOfDates FROM 12);
>
> REPEAT SET @from_date
>
> END REPEAT;
>
> END;
>   call showBugs('21/10/17 - 29/10/17');

I am really in a rut here and would be grateful if someone is to help me either with stored procedure or function implementation.

Comment: I have made a mistake while pasting from MySQL Workbench, in the first box dates should be like (dates should be at least 1 day apart):

SELECT count(DATE(Open_Date)) AS BugsOpen, DATE(Open_Date)  as Dated FROM test.bugs WHERE Date(open_date) <= > (STR_TO_DATE('21/10/17','%d/%m/%Y')) AND (Date(close_date) >= (DATE_ADD(STR_TO_DATE('22/10/17','%d/%m/%Y'), INTERVAL 1 DAY)) OR close_date is null);

Comment: `<= (STR_TO_DATE` This is SO inefficient :-(

Comment: My first care is to make this functional, then is to optimize it where it can be done.

Comment: Well, if it was me, I'd start here: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Plus, I don't understand why you think you need a function or procedure.

Comment: Because there needs to be an input, idk? Part of the requirements. If you think it could be done in a different way I am all for suggestions.

Comment: I've made the only sensible suggestion that I can at this point.